# How to move the curstor to a selected UIText Field in IOS Programming?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have created a login page with Login and Clear Button.  If the clear button is pressed the text field should clear but i need the cursor, back to username textfield but it remains in Password Field. Can anyone suggest answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

In your clear method implement this:

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIResponder's `-becomeFirstResponder` method:

```
[usernameField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
  -(void)yourclearMethod:(UIButton*)sender{

   [username_textfield becomeFirstResponder];
   }
```